# How to import image labels per language (store view) using ImportExport

Tags: import, avs-fastsimpleimport

I am using `AvS_FastSimpleImport` which is based on `Mage_ImportExport` - so answers for the latter would also help.

The images per store view are the same but I want to use different labels.

The following layout is not working. I get the image labels only in one language.

[image: Import Layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a limitation in Mage_ImportExport. The whole `_media_image` block is imported as single rows, the `_store` field isn't taken into account. Currently, I don't see an easy workaround for that, sorry.

Comment: I created an issue: https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/issues/148